I need help modifying a circuit with a DPDT to bypass some signal processing
I have a circuit I want to modify with a DPDT to bypass some signal processing but I cannot figure out how to keep the signals from mixing.
State one: signal 1 output goes through some processing and is split to signal 1 and signal 2 input
State two: signal 1 and signal 2 output bypass processing and flow straight to their respective inputs
I'm attempting to do this with a DPDT switch but I don't know how to keep my signals from mixing in state 2
This is hobby-level stuff so forgive me if used the wrong symbols/terminology
The processing is basically just a potentiometer and a diode + resistor from the original circuit I'm trying to modify.




Instead of thinking in terms of selecting where you want the signals coming into your box to go, think in terms of selecting where you want the signals going out to come from. Then it becomes quite straightforward:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that if you want "Output 1" to be completely isolated from the processing circuit in state 2, you'll need a third pole on your switch.

This is exactly what I was looking to accomplish, thank you!
